# How can I configure Apache FTPFileSystem java class to use FTPSClient instead of the FTPClient

Tags: java, hadoop, ftp, apache-commons, ftps

I am using to Apache Commons library to access files using on FTP/FTPS in my application.
The architecture of the app doesn't allow to initiate the `FTPClient`, in my case I need to use the  [Apache `FTPSClient`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/javadocs/api-3.6/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPSClient.html).

The interface only allows me to pass the path to file, configuration and a [`FileSystem` implementation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/ftp/FTPFileSystem.html).

Is there a property to set or another way to configure the `FTPFileSystem` to use the `FTPSClient` instead of the `FTPClient`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FTPFileSystem` does not support FTPS. It cannot create `FTPSClient`.

You should have to create your own implementation of `FileSystem` based on `FTPFileSystem` (changing implementation of `open`), where you initialize the client as FTPSClient not FTP client. i.e:

> FTPSClient client = new FTPSClient();

You can associate it with  `ftps://` URLs using:

```
conf.set("fs.ftps.impl", "com.myproject.MyFTPSFileSystem");
```

And you might need to set below property for the client to enter local passive mode:

```
conf.set("fs.ftp.data.connection.mode", "PASSIVE_LOCAL_DATA_CONNECTION_MODE");
```